# Nonperturbative results for $\phi^3$ theory in dimensions $d>6$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, non-perturbative

The theory is nonrenormalizeable in those dimensions, but can you say anything about the theory anyway?

Specifically I am wondering about the status of whether the theory is trivial, i.e. a generalized free field. This is the case for the $\phi^4$ theory for dimensions $d>4$, however it is clear to me that the analysis for the $\phi^3$ theory would be more complicated, since there are nonzero odd correlation functions.

Comment: try this: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.95.085001

Comment: @DanYand usually one sets the coupling to be imaginary, so that the integral converges. One expects to find a well-defined albeit non-unitary theory. This is when $\phi^3$ is relevant.

Comment: In dimensions where $\phi^3$ is irrelevant, it is indeed unclear what is meant by the $\phi^3$ theory.

Comment: Questions about QFT triviality reminds me of something David Gross said at a round table discussion during the 1994 Paris ICMP (my recollection/paraphrase): I would rather mathematicians proved that $4d$ QCD exists rather than $4d$ $\phi^4$ does not exist.